# top and grep output nothing when run from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to create shell script that ssh into a remote server and run a script there and print the output in the local server but when I run the script in the local server it most of the time outputs nothing and rarely outputs data  :

```
Mule: CPU > % RAM > %
```

and when I ssh in the local server to the remote server in the command line and run the script it outputs normally in the command line :

```
Mule: CPU > 39.0% RAM > 8.1%
```

the script in local server

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e '\r' 
echo 'leg3'
echo -e '\r'
ssh  -qT appread@${remote} << EOF
source /home/appread/Process_mon.sh 
exit
EOF
```

script in remote server :

```
#!/bin/bash
mulecpu=$(top -b -n 1 -c  | grep  -P '.*[j]ava.*mule.*'|  awk '{print $9}')
muleram=$(top -b -n 1 -c  | grep -P '.*[j]ava.*mule.*'|  awk '{print $10}')
m=$(echo 'Mule: CPU > '$mulecpu'% RAM > '$muleram'% ')
echo $m
```

Comment: `top` is an interactive tool with output that isn't standard-defined and can very between operating systems and releases of an individual operating system. It's meant for human readers, not programmatic consumption.

Comment: (and `grep -P` isn't guaranteed to work at all, as not all versions of grep are compiled against libpcre; only use it when `grep -E` isn't good enough -- but in this case, you don't need it at all, since `awk` can search for only lines that match a pattern itself).

Comment: the thing is it sometimes output data but most of the time it outputs nothing

Comment: Unspecified tools' behavior is unspecified. Something of a tautology there. I'd strongly (very, *very* strongly!) suggest monitoring behavior a different way.

Comment: For example, is your server using systemd? If so, it creates a cgroup for every service. You can easily ask the OS kernel (via `/proc`) how much memory a cgroup is using, or how many CPU cycles every process has *ever* used in it.

Comment: ...compare that CPU-time count between two samples taken at given times, take into account the number of CPUs your hardware has, and there you are -- a percentage you can calculate yourself, no need to parse output of tools that don't define their output format at all.

Comment: ...sorry, `/sys/fs/cgroup`, not `/proc`. Still, point is you can ask the kernel to give you the numbers, in a format meant to be easy for programs to interpret, directly; instead of running `top`, letting *it* collect those numbers itself, and then needing to parse its output after it munges them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `top` without `-w`, its output may be truncated and so your `grep` may fail.

Add `-w 512` or similar to maximise the width of the output:

```
#!/bin/bash

top -b -n 1 -c -w 512 |\
awk '/[j]ava.*mule/ { printf "Mule: CPU > %s%% RAM > %s%%\n",$9,$10 }'
```